# Restoring a folder to its previous state

Tags: windows

I did some rearrangements in quite a big folder and I would like to go back to the state before the changes, but I do not have any restore points or backups for the folder. Is there any solution for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Right click on the folder, and click on `Restore previous versions`. (see screenshot below):

[image]

You may have the option to either `Open`, `Copy`, or `Restore` the selected previous version of the folder. (see screenshots below):

[image]